# How to generate a PDF on the click of a link with the selected data, in java?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, itext

I have a form which shows 10 ids on a page. Based on the id, I can get the user name, role, profile etc. 
Now, if I select 5 ids and then click on the label named PRINT,  then it should download a PDF where these 5 ids with names will be displayed.
But, in my case, it doesn't print anything or method is not getting the action and id. 
There is no issue with Action, or lblpdfgenerator class. The issue is with function:

This is my JSP :

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>
        <s:actionmessage />             
        <s:if test="Count > 0">
            <a href="javascript:void();" id='addressLabel' class="printLbl"  onclick="PrintLabel()"
                    style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bolder; margin-left: 20px; color: blue;">Print
                    Label                                   
                    </a>                                        
        </s:if>                     

   <s:hidden id="docId" name="docId" value="%{docList}"></s:hidden>  
</div>

<div id="pdf-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pdfModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Print Label</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"  id="iframed"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

function PrintLabel(){
        docId= $("#docId").val();
        /*  $.get("printlabelgenerate", {DocList : docId},  function(data) {
     $("#iframed").empty();
       $("#pdf-modal").modal('show');
      }); */
       $("#iframed").empty();
       $("#pdf-modal").modal('show');
       $("#iframed").append('<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" id="pdf_framesrno"></iframe>');
       $("#pdf_framesrno").attr("src","printlabelgenerate?docId=" +  docId);
       return false;
       }
```

printlabelgenerate is my action.

Action class.

```
public String printLabel() throws Exception {
        lbList = new ArrayList<LabelPrint>();
        logger.info("Reached inside printLabel() method"+DocList);
        String[] total= DocList.split(",");
        for (String docId : total) {
        lbPrint = userService.getPrintLabel(docId); 
                ByteArrayOutputStream bs = LblPDFGenerator.createPDF(lbPrint,docId);
                myStream== = new ByteArrayInputStream(bs.toByteArray());
                if (myStream== null) {
                    this.addActionMessage("Not Generated");
                    return INPUT;
                }
                return SUCCESS;
            }
```

If I call it like this, my action hence method gets called. But it doesn't download anything.

```
function PrintLabel(){
        docId= $("#docId").val();
         $.get("printlabelgenerate", {DocList : docId},  function(data) {
     $("#iframed").empty();
       $("#pdf-modal").modal('show');
      }); 
       $("#iframed").empty();
       $("#pdf-modal").modal('show');
       $("#iframed").append('<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" id="pdf_framesrno"></iframe>');
       $("#pdf_framesrno").attr("src","printlabelgenerate?docId=" +  docId);
       return false;
       }
```

However, if calling like this only(commenting above one) :

```
$("#iframed").append('<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="600px" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" id="pdf_framesrno"></iframe>');
       $("#pdf_framesrno").attr("src","printlabelgenerate?docId=" +  docId);
       return false;
       }
```

this doesn't get into my print method as it isn't getting any id. How do I make it download the PDF? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Primefaces Extensions Document Viewer](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/documentviewer/basic.jsf) library, there is a nice and easy example of creating PDF Viewer with download functionality and more.

Example:

```
<pe:documentViewer value="#{yourViewBean.content}" download="YourPdfFile.pdf"/>
```